# .htaccess file is not getting post method in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, rest

i am using this simple .htaccess file for my rest service implementation

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]*)$ get_price.php?name=$1 [nc,qsa]
```

currently it is working fine with $_GET method and returning

```
{
status: 200
status_message: "Record found"
data: "kashif@gmail.com"
}
```

but i pass parameter using $_POST it returns

```
{
status: 200
status_message: "Record found"
data: ""
}
```

any idea where i am doing mistake. i am not expert in .htaccess files.

below is my simple testing class get_price.php.

```
<?php

header("Content-Type:application/json");
include 'header.php';
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];

 $friendResult = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM user
                    WHERE name='$name'");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($friendResult);

          $data = $row['id'];

deliver_response(200,"Record found",$data);

function deliver_response($status,$status_message,$data){

header("HTTP/1.1 $status $status_message");
$response['status'] = $status;
$response['status_message'] = $status_message;
$response['data'] = $data;

$json_response = json_encode($response);

echo $json_response ;

}


?>
```

Comment: `?key=value` are `$_GET` parameters only.

Comment: @Class how can i make them for post also

Comment: As far as I know .htaccess only deals with GET parameters(?). Maybe you need to show us what is in `get_price.php`.

Comment: Many details missing here. What URL is being sent to server and what is `get_price.php` working?

Comment: @anubhava i have edited my class . it is simple testing class i need to implement restful service for PHP post request.Can you please help me on this ....

Comment: Ok I can see the code but what URL is being sent to server in GET and POST.

Comment: for get localhost/restTest/kashif